# SQL multiple select queries into separate columns on the same table

Tags: t-sql, select

I have looked high and low for a way to do this, and several previously asked questions have similarities, but none help me with what I want to do.

This is what I have:

```
select siteid, count(dmovedin) as dmovedin

from Ledgers

where dDeleted is null and iTferFromLedID is NULL and dmovedin between '2016-05-01 00:00:00' and '2016-05-31 23:23:59'

group by siteid

order by siteid

go

select siteid, count(dMovedOut) as dmovedout

from Ledgers

where dDeleted is null and iTfertoLedID is NULL and dmovedout between '2016-05-01 00:00:00' and '2016-05-31 23:23:59'

group by siteid

order by siteid
```

Currently SQL returns **two** tables, each with a site id column and a unique column.

What I want to do is have these 2 unique columns side by side in the same table, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is the same but the second column in the select.

In that case, combine them there:

```
select siteid, count(dmovedin) as dmovedin, count(dmovedout) as dmovedout
```

Then just combine your Where:

```
where dDeleted is null 
and (iTfertoLedID is NULL 
 and iTferFromLedID is NULL)
and (dmovedin between '2016-05-01 00:00:00' and '2016-05-31 23:23:59'
**and** dmovedout between '2016-05-01 00:00:00' and '2016-05-31 23:23:59')
```

Depending on the logic you want, the bolded 'and' might be an 'or' (which is why I nested those lines in parentheses).  I don't know what you're trying to do so I can't say for sure.

Everything else should be the same.  Have you tried that?  This seems to be basic SQL.

Comment: There is another difference in that one is iTfertoledID and the other is iTferfromLedID.

Comment: Good catch...my eyes don't work as well on Friday afternoons.  Without knowing his data, it's hard to know if you can just combine those in the WHERE but I'll make the change.  It could end up filtering out all his rows but let's see where this gets him.

Comment: I don't believe that works because the iTfertoLedID is specific/exclusive to the count(dmovedout) and the iTferfromID is specific/exclusive to the count(dmoved in) which is why I am having trouble joining the two but still keeping their functions separate.

Comment: if so, we can fix that with case statements in the select.  Count(case when iTfertoLedID is null then dMovedOut else null end) as dMovedOut should do it.

Answer (score 0):

What if you transform each count query into a "table" in your query? As you have different where clauses, I think it will be easier.

```
SELECT A.siteid, A.dmovedin, ISNULL(B.dmovedout, 0) dmovedout
FROM
(
     select siteid, count(dmovedin) as dmovedin
     from Ledgers
     where dDeleted is null and iTferFromLedID is NULL and dmovedin between '2016-05-01 00:00:00' and '2016-05-31 23:23:59'
     group by siteid
     order by siteid
) A 
LEFT JOIN (
     select siteid, count(dMovedOut) as dmovedout
     from Ledgers
     where dDeleted is null and iTfertoLedID is NULL and dmovedout between '2016-05-01 00:00:00' and '2016-05-31 23:23:59'
     group by siteid
     order by siteid
) B ON A.siteid = B.siteid
```